# JSF attribute `rendered` in `rich:menuItem` can't read `boolean` value from parameter

Tags: richfaces, menuitem, jsf-1.2, param, rendered-attribute

I am using JSF 1.2_09, rich faces 3.3.3, jsf-facelets 1.1.14.

Looks like attribute `rendered` in `rich:menuItem` can't read `boolean` value from parameter `enableEdit`...
Even if `enableEdit` has `true` value, `rich:menuItem` is not rendered (not visible).

Does anyone know the solution, and is it a bug in old jsf?

```
<h:form id="mainId">
    <rich:contextMenu attached="false" id="conMenu" hideDelay="400" disableDefaultMenu="false">
        <rich:menuItem action="#{foo.edit}" rendered="{enableEdit}">
            <h:outputText value="Edit" />
            <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{someBean.id}" value="{myId}" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem action="#{foo.viw}" rendered="true">
            <h:outputText value="View" />
            <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{someBean.id}" value="{myId}" />
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:contextMenu>

    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <rich:dataTable id="tableId" value="#{someBean.results}" var="tableIter" rowClasses="oddTableRow,evenTableRow">
            ...
            ...
            <rich:componentControl event="onRowClick" for="conMenu" operation="show" params="">
                <f:param value="#{tableIter.id}" name="myId" />            
                <f:param value="#{!tableIter.locked}" name="enableEdit" />                          
            </rich:componentControl>
        </rich:dataTable>          
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

-Damjan

Comment: what is enableEdit? A bean property? a get parameter?

Comment: <f:param value="#{!tableIter.locked}" name="enableEdit" />

Comment: I would say that it is request parameter, because `f:param` (which defines `enableEdit`) is attached to `rich:componentControl`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<h:outputText rendered="{enableEdit}">
  <rich:menuItem action="#{foo.edit}">
    <h:outputText value="Edit" />
    <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{someBean.id}" value="{myId}" />
  </rich:menuItem>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Nice try, but it doesn't work. It seems like the problem is of more general nature...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<rich:menuItem action="#{foo.edit}" rendered="{param.enableEdit}">
```